# Replace "?" tiles in Corrplot

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I have a corrplot that has NA's in the correlation matrix. Corrplot replaces tiles that have `NA` in the correlation matrix with "?" (see below).  Does anyone know a way to replace these tiles with another color, rather than the questions mark?

This code gives the following image:

`corrplot(matrix(data = c(0.5,0.2,NA,NA, 0.7,0.5),nrow = 3, ncol = 2),method="shade",shade.col=NA, type = 'lower')`

[image]

The lower left tile I would like to define as a color not in the correlation color palate.

Comment: Replace the `NA` values with 0s before plotting and they should become blank white tiles.

Comment: @Zach, that would put it on the same spectrum on the correlation palate which I don't want, would give the wrong message.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two arguments you can pass to `corrplot()` to determine how `NA` values should appear: `na.label` and `na.label.col`.

You can replace the `?` with any one or two characters of text using `na.label`. Let's change it to `NA`.

```
library(corrplot)

# Add an NA column to mtcars
M <- cor(cbind(mtcars, NA))

corrplot(M, na.label = "NA")
```

[image: NA for NA]

You can also change the color of the message.

`corrplot(M, na.label = "NA", na.label.col = "orange")`

[image: Orange NA]

If you want to use a color instead of text for the `NA` boxes, set `na.label` to "square".

```
corrplot(M, na.label = "square", na.label.col = "orange")
```

[image: Orange you glad I didn't say NA]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace the fields for an empty value you could also label the values empty, e.g:
`corrplot(df, na.label = " ")`

Answer (score 0):

Best option is `corrplot(na.omit())`

Comment: I think this does provide an answer to the question.

Comment: The question was how to replace it with a standard color, not omit them all together.  This does not answer the question.